# Где взять нормальную библиотеку для swipe-событий?

Tags: javascript, jquery, swipe

Нужна библиотека для отслеживания swipe-событий (swipeleft и swiperight). Подключал jquery mobile и она работает прекрасно, но зачем-то переписывает мне css стили на свои, тем самым ломая вёрстку. Подскажите простую библиотеку для swipe-событий.

Comment: ну вообще-то можно просто не подключать стили css от JQuery UI  .... оставь просто js и будет тебе счастье. А второй момент - подключай свои стили ПОСЛЕ того, как подключаешь все модули. Тогда именно твои css будут перезаписывать чужие

Comment: ну я в принципе jquery-mobile.css и не подключал. в этом и проблема что сам файл библиотеки .js меняет некоторые стили. а насчёт подключения своих стилей после я не подумал) попробую

Comment: Если сама либа меняет стили, то они точно указаны в доках. И их не так много (именно для swipe), поэтому их можно покрыть своими стилями